# How to stop XCode from generating xcuserdata folder and xcuserstate files?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

`XCode` automatically generates files in `.xcodeproj` project file and in `.xcworkspace` etc...

> ProjectFolder.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata

this sometimes get's corrupted and make `XCode` crash upon launching or changing a window inside, how do I make `XCode` to not memorize window settings when I launch it again?

note, I locked `com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState` folder in

```
~/Library/Saved Application State/
```

and it never writes there.

**EDIT**

I made this simple shell script, and it get's the job done : https://github.com/deya-eldeen/XCodeProjectCleaner

Comment: As much as I don't _like_ those files and _Xcode in general_, I haven't seen the problem you describe… namely: "this sometimes get's corrupted and make XCode crash upon launching or changing a window inside"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write a little shell script that deletes the files you want, and then launches Xcode?  Instead of opening Xcode, open the script.

Comment: good, maybe will do one python or shell script and drop it in github later and link to it here.